# Delete all files on a server with a particular filename

Tags: linux, files

I wonder if you could help me please. I run 5GBFree.com a free hosting site. As you can imagine, it gets quite a few people signing up to abuse the service.

Recently I've found a LOT of people setting up sites with a particular script that floods forums and IRC chat rooms. The names of the files are as follows:

peindom1.php
peindom2.php
peindom3.php
peindom4.php

Is there a command I can run in linux to remove files with these filenames ANYWHERE on the server (so basically, a command to go through all folders on the server and remove instances of that name).

If you could help I would really appreciate it, and I'm sure the people who run the forums and IRC rooms getting spammed would also be grateful to you.

Kind regards,
Rob

Answer (score 3):

`find / -type f -name peindom\*.php -delete`

see the find manpage for more info on using find.  its definitely a command you want in your quiver

Comment: may I suggest first running without the -delete to verify your results first.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`find / -xdev -name 'peindom[1-4].php' -exec rm {} +`